# What is vsftpd anonymous default directory path?

Tags: directory, default, vsftpd

I've installed vsftpd on ubuntu 18.04 and I'm able to connect but I want to put a file there to check download.

I can't seem to find the default directory path for anonymous user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, the default directory for anonymous user is /srv/ftp

https://wiki.debian.org/vsftpd#Anonymous_access